# Android app with Git (EGit) - I get promted to save AndroidManifest.xml multiple times

Tags: android, eclipse, egit, eclipse-adt

I am using Eclipse ADT and Git (EGit) for developing an Android app. For some reason whenever I make a change to the AndroidManifest.xml file I have to save it several times, and it seems to require more saves as time goes on. I'm now being prompted to save it over 10 times when I make a change. I confirm the prompt and then another one pops up (after about 10 seconds, during which Eclipse is frozen).

It says the `The original file 'Android.Manifst.xml' has been deleted or is not accessible.`

This is not correct as it is not deleted/inaccessible, haven't I just been editing it for god sake!

Is this some Git related problem? It is also taking ages between prompts to save, during which Eclipse is frozen.  This is slowing down development to an unbelievably slow pace.

[image]

Comment: Just to add, even switching between files in the editor is causing Eclipse to freeze up for 20+ seconds now. This is unusable.

Comment: Could you add a bit more details, e.g. which version of Eclipse are you using (slow XML editor sounds a bit like [this bug in 4.2](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388736))? Also, you could try if the problem still exists after Team > Disconnect, to narrow down whether EGit or ADT is the problem.

Comment: I too have the same problem